# Created pod get ErrImgPull when using :latest tagged docker image

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm starting in Kubernetes and I'm trying to update the Image in DockerHub that is used for the Kubernetes's Pod creation and then with `kubectl rollout restart deployment deploymentName` command it should pull the newest image and rebuild the pods.
The problem I'm facing is that it only works when I specify a version in the tag both in the image and the deployment.yaml` file.

In my repo I have 2 images `fixit-server:latest` and `fixit-server:0.0.2` (the actual latest one).

With `deployment.yaml` file set as

```
spec:
      containers:
      - name: fixit-server-container
        image: vinnytwice/fixit-server
        # imagePullPolicy: Never
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "128Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
```

I run `kubectl apply -f infrastructure/k8s/server-deployment.yaml` and it gets created, but when running `kubectl get pods` I get

```
vincenzocalia@vincenzos-MacBook-Air server-node % kubectl get pods
NAME                            READY   STATUS         RESTARTS   AGE
fixit-server-5c7bfbc5b7-cgk24   0/1     ErrImagePull   0          7s
fixit-server-5c7bfbc5b7-g7f8x   0/1     ErrImagePull   0          7s
```

I then instead specify the version number in the `deployment.yaml` file

```
 spec:
      containers:
      - name: fixit-server-container
        image: vinnytwice/fixit-server:0.0.2
        # imagePullPolicy: Never
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "128Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
```

run again `kubectl apply -f infrastructure/k8s/server-deployment.yaml` and get `configured` as expected.
Running `kubectl rollout restart deployment fixit-server` I get `restarted` as expected.
But still running `kubectl get pods` shows

```
vincenzocalia@vincenzos-MacBook-Air server-node % kubectl get pods
NAME                            READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
fixit-server-5c7bfbc5b7-cgk24   0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          12m
fixit-server-5d78f8848c-bbxzx   0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          2m58s
fixit-server-66cb98855c-mg2jn   0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          74s
```

So I deleted the deployment and applied it again and pods are now running correctly.

Why when omitting a version number for the image to use ( which should imply :latest) the `:latest` tagged image doesn't get pulled from the repo?
What's the correct way of using the `:latest` tagged image?
Thank you very much.
Cheers

repo:
[image]

images:

```
REPOSITORY                                                TAG                                                                          IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
vinnytwice/fixit-server                                   0.0.2                                                                        53cac5b0a876   10 hours ago    1.3GB
vinnytwice/fixit-server                                   latest                                                                       53cac5b0a876   10 hours ago    1.3GB
```

Comment: In Kubernetes, you shouldn't generally use `:latest` or other fixed-string tags at all.  The Deployment mechanism sees a change in the text of the `image:` value as its signal to do something; if you use a `:latest` tag, just `kubectl apply -f` won't cause an update, you can't `kubectl rollout undo` if something goes wrong, and there's a risk of different nodes having different versions of the "latest" image.

Comment: Does your image `vinnytwice/fixit-server` have a `latest` tag? If not, you're effectively asking for `vinnytwice/fixit-server:tag-that-does-not-exist`, so of course you get an `ErrImagePull`.

Comment: @DavidMaze so you what kid of tagging  is actually useful? I mean..a tag is human readable..Docker ids aren't.  I'm following a tuto on udemy and it just follow this way.. Image with no version number( so implicitly gets the :latest), image image parameter in the deployment.yaml file without version number, and the workflow 
"change code, rebuild docker image, update to DockerHub, run `kubectl rollout restart deployment`" works perfectly.. but it might be that he's on an older version of both Docker and Kubernetes..I'm on the latest..

Comment: @larsks I added both the repo and the images in the question, the both are tagged correctly

Comment: An ordinary version number like your `0.0.2`, a date stamp, or a source control commit ID are all useful tags; the important thing is that every build has a different tag.  It does not especially need to be human-readable.

Comment: so there is no way to avoid `:version number` in the deployment.yaml file so it always look for the new image in the repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`docker_image_find_tag.sh`](https://github.com/ryandaniels/docker-script-find-latest-image-tag/blob/aed09da3813429cbe979e34a050a48c3b19a7002/docker_image_find_tag.sh) to check if your image has a `latest` tag or not.
It will show the tag/version for  shows `image:<none>` or `image:latest`.

That way, you can check if, that mentioned in "[How to fix ErrImagePull and ImagePullBackoff](https://komodor.com/learn/how-to-fix-errimagepull-and-imagepullbackoff/)" if this is linked to:

> - **Cause**: Pod specification provides an invalid tag, or fails to provide a tag
> - **Resolution**: Edit pod specification and provide the correct tag.
>   If the image does not have a latest tag, you must provide a valid tag

And:

> What's the correct way of using the `:latest` tagged image

Ideally, by *not* using it ;) `latest` can shift at any time, and by using a *fixed* label, you ensure a better reproducibility of your deployment.

Comment: HI, I updated the question, they seem to be tagged properly right? So..keeping the infrastructure using the newest code means that you have to keep editing all deployments to change the version number of the image? can't believe that..in the tuto I'm following it uses the :latest tag just because of that.. imagine you have 100's of deployments for the Microservices .. you can't possibly keep up with version numbers..hence the use of :latest tag.
Or..I can omit it in the manifest and just use it in the image building so when k8s looks for a new image it will find that there is one?

Comment: @Vincenzo Does the issue persist in your case? (I see your screenshot shows very recent push times).  And do you have a link to that tutorial?

Comment: yes, I did another test. Now I have  only `0.0.2` and `0.0.3` tags in my repo. I did try to leave the version blanking the yaml file as`image: vinnytwice/fixit-server` deleted the deployment and re applied it.. still same image pull error.
I then deleted the deal again and used the 0.0.2 tag..apllied it..pods are working correctly.. changed to 0.0.3 in the yaml file, re applied the deployment, it gets configured, now rollout restart deployment works as expected.. load are running the correct version of the code. I'm gonna try a different tag..and see if the :latest tag is causing it all

Comment: the Udemy course is "Microservices with Node JS and React" lesson 77 "Preferred Method for Updating Deployments" but is a purchased course..

Comment: Ok It looks like the `:latest` tag is the responsible for all this mess..
I created two other images `:prod` and `:dev` and now when updating the image in the repo, the `kubectl rollout restart deployment`command works as expected rebuilding the pods with the newer pushed image.

Comment: still `kubectl rollout deployment`won't roll back say from `:0.0.3` to `0.0.2`..

Comment: @Vincenzo Does the `kubectl rollout deployment` trigger the same error message or a different error message, when roll backing from `:0.0.3` to `:0.0.2`?

Comment: nope.. just says that it's rolled back but then when I log the pods they're running 0.0.3 code still.. I used `kubectl rollout undo deployment/fixit-server`command where `fixit-server`is the name of the deployment

Comment: can it be because I haven't changed the deployment.yaml to 0.0.2?

Comment: @Vincenzo Then what a `kubectl rollout status deployment/fixit-server` or `kubectl rollout history deployment/fixit-server` give you?

Comment: status gives me `deployment "fixit-server" successfully rolled out`, while history gives me `deployment.apps/fixit-server 
REVISION  CHANGE-CAUSE
2         <none>
3         <none>
4         <none>
5         <none>
7         <none>
8         <none>
9         <none>
12        <none>
13        <none>
15        <none>
16        <none>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246535/discussion-between-vonc-and-vincenzo).